# Layout is not responsive on small device (480x854)

Tags: android, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to create a new layout, but for LG k4 (480x854) the top of this layout has been cut.
I don't want to use a scroll for the time.

**Pixel 2**

[image: PIXEL 2]

**LG k4**

[image]

Note: I can't change the margin between the buttons or other component. It is a requirement for the project.

Is there way to create this layout responsive?

Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.allcreatures.AllCreaturesActivity"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/animal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/creature_dino_01" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.41" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/animal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This animal is amazing"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textSize="45sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Dinosaurs went extinct about 65 million years ago (at the end of the Cretaceous Period), after living on Earth for about 165 million years."
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/animal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="English is a complicated, but popular language. It’s one of the most popular languages in the world, in fact, and it’s prevalent in many countries. Learning English is a bit tough, but rewarding because you can use it almost anywhere. There are a surprising number of apps to help people learning English. They fall into a few different categories.  "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try to wrap your layout in a ScrollView?

Comment: Hi Juan, for the time a don't want to use the scrollView. The project requirement is to resize the layout without scroll view. :(

Comment: What about wrapping everything inside of the LinearLayout and assign weight numbers to each. That way, you won't end up with plus size

Comment: Is mandatory to use ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Your `Views` are not constrainted to the bottom of parent, that's why they are cut-off on smaller screens. You need to make everything a vertical chain and constraint it to the bottom of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

For now and for just doing your project, I suggest to set a `fixed size` to your `ImageView` like `android:layout_width="100dp"` and change the size until you get your button visible.